# What does "secondary orders" mean?

Tags: warhammer-40k

In the novel *The Warmaster* Mkoll tells a trooper:

> **"Consider us at secondary orders"**

Is there like a military list explaining meaning of this?

I remember when listening to the audiobook that every time somebody in the beginning of the books says "Secondary order" the people that hear it are really surprised. I just can't remember that when it is said what it actually means...

I am specifically asking for an in-universe answer. Maybe something in the infantryman's uplifting primer or some such. Anything from W40k where it is mentioned or even explained.

Comment: I don't know the full context, but could it mean Mkoll means a secondary or alternative objective?

Comment: I have a vague recollection that in some of the Warhammer games, perhaps old PC ones, you could give units primary and secondary orders. The secondary orders would be used if the primary was achieved. I can't find a concrete reference though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking at the phrase in the context of the book, the answer needs to be completely rewritten.

It seems that the *secondary order*, as well as *primary order* is a concept from one of tabletop game campaign rulebooks, apparently incorporated in the novel to some extent.

Using [this](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/51437988e4b0d8515d833272/t/5204cc97e4b0fdb63714be9b/1376046231733/BoltgunManualV83.pdf) as a base I speculate that "secondary order" as mentioned in the novel is an equivalent to a readiness level. This can be supported by the exchange between offcers later:

> ‘It may be nothing,’ he told them, ‘but we need to come to secondary
> order as of right now.’
>
> ‘Secondary order?’ Kolosim repeated.
>
> ‘Combat ready?’ asked Kolea.

I can't see a lot of similarity, but there is also a primary order mentioned in the novel and it clearly refers to a movement of the unit.

Comment: Do you have any in universe that this is the case here or are you just going off of the real world usage of the phrase?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - there is no indication on requirement on that way on the other in the question, so it's a real world usage.

Comment: I'm not saying it's a requirement but answers about a work generally should try and relate back to the work. This answer is probably correct but providing in universe reasoning to back it up is always best.

Comment: ye, im aware what primary and secondary objective means. im asking about specifically what "secondary order" (not objective) means in universe.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - is there a way to issue two orders to one unit at the same time "in universe"? Only thing that comes to mind is order waterfall, but it still originates with one order and there is no flexibility in the waterfall. And it's a game thing, not novel.  Answer to that is, obviously, an answer to "is there an in universe reasoning". Otherwise, sorry, no can do. Unless there is a bit more context.

Comment: @Cherubel - I dont imply you're unaware of order/objective distinction, I included it as I was thinking on objectives in a second or two after reading. So it's "just in case" for others, really. Sorry for the patronizing feeling of that. Unintended.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Please see reworked answer.

Comment: @Cherubel - please see reworked answer

Comment: @Cherubel - Looking at the indicated passage above the phrase means what you would expect. Beyond this I would ask what their primary orders were before Mkoll instructed the change AND if/what mission they attempted to accomplish afterword. It seems to me that their primary mission was either failed or completed and Mkoll tasked his unit to their secondary mission as a result.

Comment: I believe it is something rather close to "follow-up order": in "Warmaster" their primary order was to set up a base of operation. The secondary order would be become again combat ready for attack/ready to move from the camp

Comment: Ah... secondary order - combat ready bit sold me. i borrowed a book from the library yesterday just to be able to find the passage... It is as @AcePL suggests. It means that the unit must become combat ready. Thank you for finding the answer. +1